# Learning the language in an other EU country

Tags: eu-citizens

Some acquaintances who moved to France, once they got there, they have attended some French classes in which they were paid a monthly quota in order to, as said, learn the language and to integrate somehow within French society. They have EU citizenship

Is there a same thing in Belgium? I know a little bit of French but I'd like to do likewise before getting a job there, so I'm asking, is there something similar in Belgium? Are there courses in which attendants are paid a monthly quota or something like that?

Moreover, one of my friends there told me that any non-belgian EU citizen is granted at the beginning a 3-month permit, and within that related period, the person has to work at least one day, and after having satisfied this condition then they are granted, at the expiry of the permit, another 5-year permit.

If that is the case, can one day of lesson be considered as one day of work?

Note that I hold EU citizenship so I have little problems concerning papers and the like.

Comment: Have some patience. People are not waiting here to answer the moment a question is posted. They have their own lives too. Wait and someone will answer your query.

Comment: Ok dumbcoder, sorry

Comment: Since an EU-Citizen does not need either a residence or work permit for Belgium, I would say that that story is a very unconvincing fairy tale, just as 1 lesson of french is considered equivalent to 1 day of working for someone whos does not yet work.

Comment: @Mark Johson well EU citizens need to make less formalities in an other EU country, nevertheless this does not mean that there aren't conditions, otherwise the whole Romanian or Bulgarian population would move to other countries. So, for long term residence EU citizens need some residence permits as well (I'm not talking about work).

Comment: Your mixing of learning a language and permits makes no sense. Again EU-Citizens need no permit to reside in another EU Country.

Comment: @Mark Johnson a EU citizen who lives there told me otherwise, but after the 3-month one and the 5-year one, however, one gets the indefinite one

Comment: @Mark Johnson this is at the beginning. The only difference between EU nationals and non, it's that the EU residence permit can be obtained on the spot for the former.

Comment: Well they gave you incorrect information.

Comment: An EU-Citizen can, voluntarily., apply for a **residence card** which confirms that they are a resident. It is similar to a local ID card.

Comment: So are you saying that a EU citizen can reside in another EU country without pre-condition and for the time they want? All well that it is the EU and for its citizens there's no need of a work permit, but it seems strange that conditions are not required for residence (whether residence permit card is mandatory or not).

Comment: @Mark Johnson https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=LEGISSUM:l33152

Comment: Anyway I'm not here to lecture anyone, I'm the asker, but I'm asking if there are paid language courses and under certain conditions, how am I going to satisfy them in a slightly different way or if that different way falls under the category of the way prescribed itself. I wish there were no pre-conditions whatsoever.

Comment: Look for local language schools and/or the local employment office if they offer any integration courses which help in gaining language skills. And it a **residence card** (without *permit*) - there is a legal difference. The card also helps when looking for a job since it proves that no permits are needed. Also useful for many everyday things.

Comment: @abdul There are some conditions on long-term stay... but there is no requirement to get a permit. That's not exactly the same thing. But it's true that Belgium is one of the countries that's most proactive in enforcing these restrictions and you will need to [register with the municipality](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/residence/documents-formalities/registering-residence/index_en.htm).

Comment: @Relaxed with residence permit I meant residence card.

Comment: "The card also helps when looking for a job since it proves that no permits are needed": an EU passport or national ID card also proves that.