# Obligation on whether to request a residence card in a EU country as a EU non-citizen of the latter

Tags: eu-citizens

From [this](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/19498/learning-the-language-in-an-other-eu-country) question some comments below the very question made 
me rethink about a thing that I did not know.

Regarding EU countries who mandate to other EU citizens to report their presence for long-term stays (or even short ones as well), are the latter people going to receive mandatorily a residence card (with a validity and to be renewed further for a more extended period) (specific for EU nationals) or can they simply report their presence only and get a printed certificate and stay there indefinitely as they wish without conditions?

In the EU site this thing is not mentioned, but some people told me otherwise.

Comment: What does "...a[n] EU on-citizen of the latter..." mean?

Comment: It means any other EU citizen which is not a citizen of that EU country.

Comment: @DavidsupportsMonica What he wants to know is in how far another EU Citizen is equal to a local EU-Citizen based on EU law.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Thanks. Won't the answer differ depending upon what country the OP is a citizen of, and the identify of the EU country being considered for residence?

Comment: @DavidsupportsMonica From the local registration laws of about 5 countries that I have read, they all quote this directive and the issuing of a **residence card** is not mandatory (but I have not read them all). Spain has strict ID laws where it may be different. But this question may bring answers to that. So I would not close it.

Comment: Thanks again. You'll see I already withdrew my VTC.

Answer (score 1):

Where local residence laws exist, the other EU-Citizens must comply with these laws just as local EU-Citizens must.

For 3rd Country Citizens registration requirements *may* exist that do not apply to EU-Citizens (mostly matters pertaining to their **residence permit**).

Other EU-Citizens **may** (but are not required to) apply for a **residence card**, which fulfills a similar function as a local ID for identification purposes.

Otherwise other EU-Citizens are treated as a local citizens, with the major exception for activities where the national citizenship is a requirement (voting in National elections etc.).

An other EU-Citizen can, however, be **deported** when certain conditions are fulfilled:

- criminal record/activities
- when conditions, set in **bold** below in the **KEY POINTS**,  are fulfilled

---

[EU freedom of movement and residence](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=LEGISSUM:l33152)

> **KEY POINTS**
>
> EU citizens with a valid identity card or passport may:
>
> Enter another EU country without requiring an exit or entry visa. Family members who are not nationals of a EU country are not required either an exit or entry visa if they possess a valid residence card.
>
> - Live in another EU country for up to 3 months without any conditions or formalities.
> - Live in another EU country for longer than 3 months subject to certain conditions, depending on their status in the host country. Those who *are employed or self-employed do not need to meet any other conditions*. Students and other people not working for payment, such as those in retirement, **must have sufficient resources for themselves and their family, so as not to be a burden on the host country’s social assistance system, and comprehensive sickness insurance cover**.
> - Have to register with the relevant authorities if living in the country longer than 3 months. Their family members, if not EU nationals, are required [to] a residence card valid for 5 years.
> - Be entitled to permanent residence if they have lived legally in another EU country for a continuous period of 5 years. This also applies to family members.
> - Have the right *to be treated on an equal footing with nationals of the host country*. However, host authorities **are not obliged to grant benefits to EU citizens not working for payment during the first 3 months of their stay**.

Comment: @abdul I didn't make these conditions. Working for 3 months is not a high condition. You can't expect the Citizens of another country to support you for the rest of your life just because you have moved to their country.

Comment: No it wasn't a rant, in fact I'm willing to work. However...many whom I know in France live just out of welfare, so they know tricks.